# Защита от ботов

Tags: алгоритм, защита

Какие **НЕСТАНДАРТНЫЕ** ***методы*** существуют для ***защиты сайта от ботов***, чтобы они не могли тыкать и посылать запросы по определенной ссылке? Какие у Вас ***оригинальные мысли*** есть по этому вопросу? :)

Captcha меня не устраивает, т.к. она достаточно надоедливая штука, и не оригинальная...

**Почему я задаю этот вопрос, а не ищу в интернете:**

В интернете конечно есть кучу информации по этому вопросу, и гугл выдаст мне `примерно 6 770 000 (0,15 сек.)` данных. Но на первых местах будут статьи, ссылки, теории о стандартных методах ухода от ботов. А **чем более стандартный метод защиты** - тем больше над обходом этого метода задействовано средств. Т.е. - ***тем более стандартный существует метод обхода***.

*Поэтому* я решил задать вопрос тут, и **узнать мысли у Наших Специалистов**!

---

**Известные мне защиты:**

> **Капча-обыкновенная** (она же картинка) - дается пользователю картинка с искаженным текстом, необходимо ввести этот текст.

***Недостатки:*** Многие виды современных капчей-картинок распознать тяжело, даже если Вы не робот.

***Вариант обхода:*** Распознается с помощью OCR или специальных сервисов типа антигейт

> **Текстовая капча** (или вопрос-ответ) - дается пользователю текст (или картинка) с вопросом, например сложите 2 числа.

***Недостатки:*** Есть вероятность, что человек может не знать ответа.

***Вариант обхода:*** Обход по составляемой для популярных ресурсов базе, обновляемая база входит в комплект хрумера. Распознавание с помощью 3-их лиц, сервисы типа антигейт.

> **Интерактивная капча** - дается пользователю задание, которая решается манипуляцией объектов на странице. Например есть 4 картинки с надписями (1,2,3,4) их необходимо перетащить в область по возрастанию. [Вот например](http://www.keycaptcha.com).

***Недостатки*** Необходимо тестировать на всех браузерах (или ограничивать браузеры)

***Вариант обхода*** В принципе можно ухитриться на JS, но тут надо хорошо подумать бото-писателю )

> **Ловушка для бота** - создаются невидимые элементы, всё что угодно, и бот либо попадает в эту область, либо он заполняет лишние данные, из-за которых действие не будет произведено.

***Варианты обхода*** эмулятор браузера, бот бродит в точности как человек.

> ***Еще одно ухищрение JS*** - при нажатии на кнопку, отправляются координаты нажатия на кнопку

***Варианты обхода*** ботописателю надо немного посидеть и посмотреть почему его бот не проходит (но т.к. все мы люди, то возможно он решит не связываться)

> **сервисы фильтрации спама** основана на вычленении каких-то признаков спама из текста сообщений и может быть IP адресов, может быть куках браузера

***Недостатки*** Не способна защитить формы регистрации, или какие-либо другие произвольные формы

***Вариант обхода*** С помощью управляемого браузера и не сильно агрессивного поведения бота, можно спамить

---

Вот, что первым пришло в голову :) Суть вопроса еще в том, чтобы немного повысить свой багаж знаний. По данным ответам и комментариям уже появились новые мысли в этом направлении...

Comment: Извините, но даже гугл в первой десятке, дает несколько неплохих вариантов. Трудно поискать перед тем ка спрашивать?

Comment: хороший комментарий - http://habrahabr.ru/post/66915/#comment_1896655

Comment: @jimpanzer несомненно, в интернете есть ответ, но в том же интернете так же полно мусора. На тысячу первых постов в гугле будет только пару нестандартных идей. А любые стандартные идеи в области защиты означают, что для них есть не менее стандартные обходы...

Comment: @jimpanzer тот метод на хабре имеет немного больше минусов. Например его легко обойти :) Т.е. чтобы обойти защиту и написать под него бота надо пару минут посмотреть на html код... Да и методы с эмуляциями браузеров тоже легко обойдет защиту, даже без анализа кода.

Comment: Ок, тогда правильный вопрос звучал бы по другому: Я ищу способ защиты от ботов. Попробывал это - недостатки такието, далее это - недостатки такие-то......... Нужен метод, который бы удовлетворял вот этим условиям: 1...2...3...4....5...6....

Comment: Если хотите "НЕСТАНДАРТНЫЕ методы", то уберите регистрацию на сайте вообще. Авторизация только через гугл акк.

Comment: Да, и инвайт систему тоже никто не отменял.

Comment: дело не только в регистрации )

Comment: А что именно вы хотите защитить от бота?

Comment: @Чад отличный вопрос между прочим

Comment: @Denis убрал p.s. и добавил первое что пришло в голову, до тех пор, пока не стало лень ) А минусы нахватал больше от первоначального заданного вопроса. Любое кол-во минусов покроют хорошие ответы (а такие уже есть)

@Чад в оригинале, когда писал вопрос, для небольшой моей игрушки - поединок начинается нажатием одной ссылки (сам бой проходит автоматические), дальше можно опять жать на ссылку, так вот, хочу избавиться от бота, который сутками сидит и жмет на ссылку "драться". Но дальше во мне проснулся интерес к этому вопросу )

Comment: вводите таймауты. 30-60 секунд между боями, количество боев в день. боты для игр - дело обычное, все зависит от игры, чем сложнее геймплей, тем интереснее играть, тем меньше нужен бот... это так мысли в слух, без привязки к контексту.

Comment: Генерите картинкой имя противника(или противников) и просите ввести результата боя, при этом таблицу резултатов тоже генерите картинкой. Думаю этого будет достаточно. Результат боя выводите отдельной страницей, при этом например инвертируйте тоже в случайном порядке т.е. надо ввести результаты для Противник1 а в таблице Противник 2 победил Противник 1.

Comment: Троллей то набежало...

Comment: Возможно сервис botfaqtor защитит от ботов, мы тестируем, вроде хорошо справляется...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну хорошо, давайте устроим мозговой штурм.

1. Замените ссылки *a href=...* на css-класс + привязанным к этому классу события в js.
2. Уберите ссылки вообще, пусть ваши пользователи вместо этого пишите инструкции для пользователей (*Чтобы выполнить запрос А, добавьте к адресу текущей страницы GET-параметр B со значением C...*)
3. Сделайте сайт в фреймах, нижний фрейм будет выполнять роль консоли, в которой пользователь пишет некоторые данные, которые от него требуются в верхнем фрейме. Данные будут синхронизироваться при помощи localStotage, comet или ajax.
4. Используйте ссылки-капчи. Допустим есть ссылка "Продолжить", после нее в скобках стоит (нажмите на первую половину слова).
5. Вариант п. 4. Сделайте три ссылки "Продолжить" с указанием какую именно их них нажать (ссылки могут быть разного цвета).

Comment: да ) есть над чем подумать )

Comment: еще можно хранить в href одну ссылку, при наведении мышки менять адрес (или добавлять событие), при выходе из ссылки обратно ставить ложную

Comment: большинство ботов на страницу заходят только один раз (точнее ботописатели), чтоб понять откуда берутся данные для post и get запросов. для спамботов оригинальные разработки обычно малопривлекательны, в силу того, что под каждый такой сайт писать свой скрипт лень. проще найти сайты на vb, wp и на других популярных движках и спамить туда без особых хлопот с капчами и прочими причудами, вплоть до регистрации тыщ пользователей, мега постинга и т.д.

Comment: Ещё [ссылка по теме](http://vimeo.com/19260629).

Answer (score 2):

- Фильтрация пользователей без поддержки JS & cookie.
- Ограничение периодичности запросов на сервер.
- В hidden readonly input средствами JavaScript записывается хеш-код информации всех полей формы. Значение повторно вычисляется на сервере и сравнивается с полученным.
- [Проверка useragent](http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/)
- Установить минимально допустимое время на заполнение формы.
- Обфускация или шифрование HTML & JS
- Установка капчи только для неавторизированных пользователей или новичков.
- [Вот](http://pastebin.com/dmKgwteg) еще мой любимый, но немного странный способ (перенаправление запросов через JS).

Comment: Извините, но только "минимально допустимое время на заполнение формы" действительно является препятствием. все остальное обходится. даже оборачивание всего этого в отдельный фрейм и в флеш не спасает (как пример дс-гейм.ру). ни get ни post вы не сможете спрятать так, чтоб его нельзя было проэмулировать. в том числе капчи, которые мешают больше легальным пользователям, чем спасают от спама/ботоводства.  
ну если только это не "неуловимый джо", который никому не нужен.

Comment: Все вышеперечисленные методы являются препятствиями для ботов и мелких хацкеров. Именно потому Я про них и упомянул. Вопрос в том, насколько они эффективны.
Более того, лично Я считаю, что ограничение времени заполнения формы менее эффективно, чем введение тайм-аутов между запросами на сервер.
Но единого универсального решения нету и потому, чем больше методов защиты применено, тем лучше.

Comment: Насчет пользы капчи, так это абсолютно беспочвенное заявление с Вашей стороны. Другими словами — балаболство. Исследование этого вопроса соразмерно с написанием цикла научных статей или популярной научной работы.
Нужно учитывать многие факторы (в т.ч. психологические), проводить сбор и анализ статистики, изучение альтернативных методов защиты и сопоставление эффективности... Вы всем этим занимались что бы вот так про100 написать: "числе капчи, которые мешают больше легальным пользователям, чем спасают от спама/ботоводства" ?

Comment: Периодичность запросов на сервер - это ограничение никакому боту не страшно, все закончится за три-пять запросов, вы просто не сумеете бота отфильтровать. Потом смена прокси и ловите дальше.  
Позвольте ознакомиться с вашими статьями о пользе капчи. Хамоватый тон, видимо заразен, не с тех участников пример берете. Всем этим я занимался (именно в исследовательских целях), могу вас уверить, что пройти капчу за деньги через спец сервисы или автоматом через ocr - небольшое препятствие. ТС, кстати об этом упомянул, вы видимо плохо читали вопрос.