# Проверка формы

Tags: php

Всем добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста способы проверки формы. Имеется в виду защита от спама. С помощью PHP. И способы защититься от подделки форм.

Comment: Не понятно, что вы подразумеваете.

Защита от спама в форму? Капча + грамотная проверка на сервере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. При генерации формы вставляем hidden поле с хэшем чего-нибудь. Этот хэш можем записать в БД со значением, что его еще не использовали. Когда приходит ответ от формы, смотрим в БД, если не использовали, то применяем действие и записываем в БД флаг, что использовали. От подделки также поможет скрытое поле с хэшем. Можете покапать еще насчет CSRF-токена.
2. От спама - капча.
3. Можно ограничить кол-во действий за T секунд. Например, форму нельзя отправлять 2 раза за 5 секунд.

Вы используете чистый php или фреймворки?

**Добавлено:**

Возможно вам будет интересен [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/245048/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Чистый PHP. Поэтому интересует простые методы создания динамических токенов. Капча не интересна, так как идет подделка формы.

Comment: И есть ли еще методы защиты, кроме тех, что приведены выше?

Comment: @alexsis20102 Вам написал @IVsevolod в первом пункте: CSRF-token.
Несколько замечаний по созданию оного:

 * Созданный токен стоит хранить в сессии. Лишний раз беспокоить СУБД ни к чему.
 * Достаточно одного уникального хеш-токена за http-сессию, т.е. на странице может быть несколько форм, а также, некие ссылки, которым возможно тоже потребуется указать токен (к примеру, ссылка logout: http://site.com/?service=logout&csrf=BUmc1CaCR). Генерация для каждого конкретного случая хеш-токена, является избыточным. 
 * Дополнительно можно сделать автоматическое [обнуление токена](http://goo.gl/QvnbEu)

Comment: Согласен с замечанием ) Обычно обращение к СУБД довольно накладная штука на крупных проектах. И да, csrf-token храниться в сессиях. Довольно сумбурно получилось, но в первом пункте я включил 2-3 идеи:

1. csrf-token (форма срабатывает для данной сессии пользователя и домена).

2. Каждая сгенеренная форма может обработаться 1 раз.